# Highlighting dates in flutter calendar

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar

So I've created a basic calendar using flutter's table_calendar package.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';

 class Calendar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
 _CalendarState createState() => _CalendarState();
 }

 class _CalendarState extends State<Calendar> {
   CalendarFormat format = CalendarFormat.month;
   DateTime selectedDay = DateTime.now();
   DateTime focusedDay = DateTime.now();

   TextEditingController _eventController = TextEditingController();


  @override
   void dispose() {
    _eventController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text("ESTech Calendar"),
       centerTitle: true,
     ),
     body: Column(
        children: [
         //defining min an max years
         TableCalendar(
            focusedDay: selectedDay,
            firstDay: DateTime(1990),
            lastDay: DateTime(2050),

          //changing calendar format
        calendarFormat: format,
        onFormatChanged: (CalendarFormat _format) {
          setState(() {
            format = _format;
          });
        },
        startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
        daysOfWeekVisible: true,

        //Day Changed on select
        onDaySelected: (DateTime selectDay, DateTime focusDay) {
          setState(() {
            selectedDay = selectDay;
            focusedDay = focusDay;
          });
          print(focusedDay);
        },
        selectedDayPredicate: (DateTime date) {
          return isSameDay(selectedDay, date);
        },


        //To style the Calendar
        calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
          isTodayHighlighted: true,
          selectedDecoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue,
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          ),
          selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          todayDecoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.purpleAccent,
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          ),
          defaultDecoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          ),
          weekendDecoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          ),
        ),
        headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
          formatButtonVisible: true,
          titleCentered: true,
          formatButtonShowsNext: false,
          formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          ),
          formatButtonTextStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

and the out put is such,
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCFst.png)

what I want is to input some dates using a list or some sort and I want the calendar to highlight those days like in the picture below

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsjNs.png)

Please help me achieve it.Should I use events ? if so please tell me how to !!!

Answer (score 15):

Add a list of `DateTime` as parameter to your `Calendar` widget:

```
class Calendar extends StatefulWidget {
  const Calendar({
    required this.toHighlight,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CalendarState createState() => _CalendarState();

  final List<DateTime> toHighlight;
}
```

Inside the calendar `Build`, add the `calendarBuilders` property.
Within this property you can use the `defaultBuilder` option to override the cell widget in specific cases:

```
calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
              defaultBuilder: (context, day, focusedDay) {
                for (DateTime d in widget.toHighlight) {
                  if (day.day == d.day &&
                      day.month == d.month &&
                      day.year == d.year) {
                    return Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.lightGreen,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(8.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          '${day.day}',
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
```

As you can see I've implemented a basic comparison between the cell date and the dates which sent as `toHighlight` parameter.

If you want your highlighted cells to maintain their new apparence even if focused or selected, you can use the `prioritizedBuilder` property.

Here's the Docs references:

[CalendarBuilders Docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/table_calendar/latest/table_calendar/CalendarBuilders-class.html)

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as the correct answer so that other people know.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use selectedDayPredicate

From https://github.com/aleksanderwozniak/table_calendar/blob/master/example/lib/pages/multi_example.dart

```
 TableCalendar<Event>(
            ...
            selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
              // Use values from Set to mark multiple days as selected
              return _selectedDays.contains(day);
            },
```

Comment: Doesnt this show the selected dates? I believe the goal here is just to have highlights on dates that have a value in them

Answer (score 0):

To mark the day that is tapped on flutter TableCalendar

```
 selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
            return _focusedDay.year == day.year &&
                _focusedDay.month == day.month &&
                _focusedDay.day == day.day;
          },
```