# How to high light the holidays date in the tableCaldender

Tags: flutter, dart

```
TableCalendar(
                                calendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
                                daysOfWeekHeight: 20,
                                daysOfWeekStyle: DaysOfWeekStyle(
                                  weekdayStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    fontSize: 14.0,
                                  ),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: lightColor,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                      topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                      topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                                    titleCentered: true,
                                    formatButtonVisible: false,
                                    leftChevronIcon: Icon(
                                      Icons.keyboard_arrow_left,
                                      color: buttoncolor,
                                    ),
                                    rightChevronIcon: Icon(
                                      Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                                      color: buttoncolor,
                                    ),
                                    titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    )),
                                calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                                  markerSize: 40,
                                  outsideDaysVisible: false,
                                  todayTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  todayDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: AppColor.transparent,
                                      shape: BoxShape.circle),
                                  selectedDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: AppColor.orange,
                                    border: Border.all(
                                      color: AppColor.orange,
                                      width: 1,
                                      strokeAlign:
                                          BorderSide.strokeAlignOutside,
                                    ),
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                rowHeight: 35,
                                firstDay: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 60)),
                                lastDay: DateTime.now(),
                                focusedDay: _currentDate,
                                onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
                                  if (!isSameDay(_selectedDate, selectedDay)) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _selectedDate = selectedDay;
                                      _currentDate = focusedDay;
                                      controller.seeAttendance(
                                          context: context,
                                          selectedDate: _selectedDate);
                                    });
                                  }
                                },
                                holidayPredicate: (day) {
                                  /// Check if the current day is a holiday
                                  String formattedDay = "${day.year}-${day.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${day.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}";
                                  return controller.fetchMonthAttendance.contains(formattedDay);
                                },
                                calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
                                  defaultBuilder: (context, day, focusedDay) {
                                    List<DateTime> datesAsDateTime = controller.fetchMonthAttendance.map((dateString) => DateTime.parse(dateString)).toList();
                                    for (DateTime d in datesAsDateTime) {
                                      if (day.day == d.day &&
                                          day.month == d.month &&
                                          day.year == d.year) {
                                        return Container(
                                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Colors.lightGreen,
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(8.0),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          child: Center(
                                            child: Text(
                                              '${day.day}',
                                              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      }
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                ),
                                selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
                                  return isSameDay(_selectedDate, day);
                                },
                                onFormatChanged: (format) {
                                  if (_calendarFormat != format) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _calendarFormat = format;
                                    });
                                  }
                                },
                                onPageChanged: (focusedDay) {
                                  _currentDate = focusedDay;
                                },
                                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

By using flutter built in I thinks its a difficult task. However I can suggest to use the syncfusion calendar. It has many flexibilities avaialble

https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answered.

[see more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71078498/highlighting-dates-in-flutter-calendar)